# Roku / BrightScript : Changing Button width inside a ButtonGroup

Tags: roku, brightscript

I have a custom component that is extending Dialog. Im adding the buttons using a custom array and I only have 1 button

```
m.buttonGroup = m.top.buttonGroup
m.buttonGroup.maxWidth = 50
m.buttonGroup.minWidth = 50

buttonLabels = []
buttonLabels.push("Some Button")
m.top.buttons = buttonLabels
```

When this Dialog is displayed, the width of the Button is using up almost all the available width, clearly not 50 as it was defined.

I also tried accessing the buttons once added but no luck. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Weird - are you saying that `.minWidth` and `.maxWidth` get totally ignored (bug?) or is it only when the value forced is less than the actual width of the label?

Answer (score 0):

```
        <Poster
        id="noButtonContainer"
        uri="pkg:/images/no_btn.png"            
        width="328"
        height="53"
        translation="[65,250]" />

    <Poster
        id="yesButtonContainer"
        uri="pkg:/images/no_btn.png"            
        width="328"
        height="53"
        translation="[431,250]" />

    <ButtonGroup id="yesNoButton" layoutDirection="horiz" minWidth="328" itemSpacings="[38, 0]" translation="[65,250]" >
        <Button
           id="noButton"             
           focusBitmapUri="pkg:/images/yes_btn.png"                
           iconUri=""
           focusedIconUri=""
           height="55"                               
           textFont="font:MediumSystemFont"
           focusedTextFont="font:MediumBoldSystemFont"                 
           text="         NO"/>                     
        <Button
           id="yesButton"
           focusBitmapUri="pkg:/images/yes_btn.png"                
           iconUri=""
           focusedIconUri=""                   
           height="55"                              
           textFont="font:MediumSystemFont"
           focusedTextFont="font:MediumBoldSystemFont"
           text="        YES"/>                                            
     </ButtonGroup>
```